# kinect_aux compilation errors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having some issues getting kinect_aux to compile cleanly under diamondback.

This is the 2nd hour I have logged working with ROS, so forgive me if I've missed the obvious.  I get compile errors @ lines 108 and 110 -- publish methods on comm classes I think...

I got rid of the error on line 108 by changing the double cast to float64_t -- but the error on 110 remains -- despite various attempts to cast to class happy types..

Compiler output is at the end -- here is the code localized -- if the two publish method calls are commented out -- all compiles -- but I want to change the tilt -- so thats moot.

// publish tilt angle and status -- ORIGINAL

```
    if (pub_tilt_angle.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
            pub_tilt_angle.publish(double(tilt_angle) / 2.);
    if (pub_tilt_status.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
            pub_tilt_status.publish(tilt_status);
```

// publish tilt angle and status -- FIXED 108

```
    if (pub_tilt_angle.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
            pub_tilt_angle.publish(float64_t(tilt_angle) / 2.);
    if (pub_tilt_status.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
            pub_tilt_status.publish(tilt_status);
```

Error snippet...

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesnect_aux: 1.3 sec ] [ kinect_camera: 0.6 sec ]                                                                                                                                                                             [ 2 Active 57/60 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kinect_aux_node.dir/src/kinect_aux.o
  In file included from /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h:35,
                   from /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:34,
                   from /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                   from /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                   from /home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/src/kinect_aux.cpp:2:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = double]’:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:250:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = double]’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:111:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = double]’
  /home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/src/kinect_aux.cpp:108:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = double]’:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:259:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = double]’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:111:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = double]’
  /home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/src/kinect_aux.cpp:108:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:138: error: request for member ‘__getDataType’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = unsigned char]’:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:250:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = unsigned char]’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:111:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = uint8_t]’
  /home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/src/kinect_aux.cpp:110:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const unsigned char’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = unsigned char]’:
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:259:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = unsigned char]’
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:111:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = uint8_t]’
  /home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/src/kinect_aux.cpp:110:   instantiated from here
  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:138: error: request for member ‘__getDataType’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const unsigned char’
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/kinect_aux_node.dir/src/kinect_aux.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/kinect_aux_node.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/markc/kinect-devel/kinect/kinect_aux/build'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9199/kinect_aux-compilation-errors/) by [weaponeer](https://answers.ros.org/users/187/weaponeer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmm, I don't see how that ever would have worked. Maybe the author forgot to push a later commit. Anyhow, try changing that block of code to this, which actually compiles and seems to work (at least, data is published--I can't say if it's right or not):

```
// publish tilt angle and status
if (pub_tilt_angle.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
  std_msgs::Float64 angle_msg;
  angle_msg.data = tilt_angle/2;
  pub_tilt_angle.publish(angle_msg);
}

if (pub_tilt_status.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
  std_msgs::UInt8 status_msg;
  status_msg.data = tilt_status;
  pub_tilt_status.publish(status_msg);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1